# python multiprocessing with multiple cpus?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two Xeon processors (each has 8 cores, so total 32 threads) on my MOBO, and I ran a simple code using multiprocessing.Pool(processors=30). When I monitor using htop, I find that only 12 threads are utilized. Does anyone know why that might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that you are processing more than 12 items (in your `map` for example)?

Comment: Yes, I had 1080 files (each file is a 3d array of size 0.5-1.5 GB) and I assigned 36 to each process (30 total). In the end it used maybe about 16-20 threads but didn't seem using all requested 30 (I didn't keep monitoring since each process took long time). Maybe some threads were doing IO like Genuine mentioned..?

Answer (score 1):

`Pool()` can provide a specified number of processes for user invocations when a new request is submitted to the Pool, and if the Pool is not full, a new process is created to execute the request; But if the number of processes in the pool has reached the specified maximum, the request will wait until there is a process in the pool to create a new process.
For a model that supports multi-threading, the number of threads recommended is at least 1:1. 5. This allows some threads to do IO.
And if your process doesn't use a full core, it won't take up another core.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.